# Why my GAN generate a bunch of noises instead of a readable picture?

Tags: python, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

Here is my code below:
The definition of discriminator:

```py
def discriminator():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5,5), strides=(2,2), padding='same', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (5,5), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1))
    return model
```

Definition of generator:

```py
def generator():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(7*7*256, input_dim=100))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Reshape((7,7,256)))
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (4,4), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
    model.add(Conv2D(1, (7,7), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))
    return model
```

The model that d_on_g:

```py
def gan(generator, discriminator):
    generator.trainable = False
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(generator)
    model.add(discriminator)
    discriminator.trainable = True
    return model
```

The optimizer i have using Adam:

```py
optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-3)
optimizer = mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer(optimizer)
```

The loss function here i use wasserstein:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
def wasserstein_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_true * y_pred)
```

Initalization and compile:

```py
d = discriminator()
d.compile(loss=wasserstein_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
g = generator()
g.compile(loss=wasserstein_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
gan = gan(g, d)
gan.compile(loss=wasserstein_loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Step of training:

```py
def train_discriminator(x_train, batch_size):
    valid = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
    fake = -np.ones((batch_size, 1))
    d_loss_valid = d.train_on_batch(x_train, valid)
    gen = g.predict(np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, 100)))
    d_loss_fake = d.train_on_batch(gen, fake)
    d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_valid, d_loss_fake)
    for l in d.layers:
        weights = l.get_weights()
        weights = [np.clip(w, -0.01, 0.01) for w in weights]
        l.set_weights(weights)
    return [d_loss, d_loss_valid, d_loss_fake]


def train_generator(batch_size):
    valid = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, 100))
    return gan.train_on_batch(noise, valid)
```

Training function:

```py
def train(x_train, epochs, batch_size):
    with tqdm(total=epochs,unit="iters") as pbar:
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            d_loss, d_loss_valid, d_loss_fake = train_discriminator(x_train, batch_size)
            g_loss = train_generator(batch_size)
            pbar.set_description('Epoch {0}'.format(epoch+1))
            pbar.set_postfix(
                d_loss='{0:.4f}'.format(d_loss[0]),
                g_loss='{0:.4f}'.format(g_loss[0]),
                d_loss_valid='{0:.4f}'.format(d_loss_valid[0]),
                d_loss_fake='{0:.4f}'.format(d_loss_fake[0]),
            )
            pbar.update(1)
```

The generate function:

```py
def generate():
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1, 100))
    gen_imgs = g.predict(noise)
    plt.imshow(gen_imgs[0].reshape(28,28),cmap='gray')
```

So after i training it in 1000 epochs and i get the result from generator looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7TaQ.png)
So how should i do to let my network working fine?I'm beginer to hands on GAN.

Comment: `generator.trainable = False`?

Comment: sorry,my bad lol.
Other wise,is there any onther wrong here?